# inline-block does not wrap text while block wraps text

Tags: css, display

I have the following lines of code

```
<style>
p {
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>

<body>

<p>These two paragraphs generates inline boxes, and it results in</p>

<p>no distance between the two elements.</p>
```

Now when I make the browser window smaller, as soon as the text "no distance between the two elements" cannot be contained in the same line it moves that whole "p" element to the second line.  If I change the display to either "inline" or "block" then this does not happen and it wraps.  Can someone please explain this behavior.

Comment: `inline-block` _means_ `inline-block`. It keeps all the contents in a block which, however, is placed within the line, so the whole block is realigned instead of single elements (words) in it. A typical example of an inline-block element is an image. Imagine your content of an inline-block element as being graphics content (regarding the layout).

Comment: If this is the case then shouldn't I see the same behavior when I use "block" as well for display?  However when I use block the text wraps.

Comment: When using `display:block` you should see the two paragraphs separated anyway. Exception: `flex` layout or `float: (left|right)` is used (or even a table)